# Is the effect of music on stress just due to beat entrainment?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, stress, music, brain

Different music genres have different beat and rhythm patterns. The lower beat and rhythm frequencies are similar to the frequency of heartbeat and this relax us.
However in my opinion, it's relevant to consider also the emotional significance which the song has for a person.

**How does the brain form a link between the emotional of a song and the stress system?**

Comment: This is an interesting question.  Have you done any research on this? So we don't repeat what you have researched already what can you share about your research and what problems do you have with it?

Comment: Sure... i didn't make a research. I was reading a short [article](http://www.apa.org/monitor/2013/11/music.aspx) on "music as therapy", and particularly i found interesting the last part in which they describe results of the use of a vibroacustic therapy with parkinson's disease patients